# In emacs how can I kill multiple buffers without opening each individually

Tags: emacs

I have a lot (~30) of buffers whose names start with the same substring. Is there a way I can pass a regular expression to the kill buffer command so I can kill all of them in one go?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The command I was looking for `M-x kill-matching-buffers`.

Comment: do you know about `ibuffer` to do it interactively ? type `% f` to mark buffers by file name and `D` to delete them.

Answer (score 32):

1. Run M-x *ibuffer* (built-in command).
2. On each line with a buffer you want to delete press 'd'.
3. When finished press 'x' to commit changes.

Answer (score 23):

A more interactive and versatile approach is with `helm-buffers-list`:

1. Type what you want to match.
2. Select all matches with <kbd>M-m</kbd> (`helm-toggle-all-marks`).
3. Optionally, refine your selection with <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> (`helm-toggle-visible-marks`),
   using <kbd>C-n</kbd>/<kbd>C-p</kbd> to navigate.
4. Press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, select "kill buffers" from the available options.
   Other options are query-replace / occur / grep / revert, and a bunch of others.

Comment: I had an easier time copying `(global-set-key (kbd "M-D") 'helm-buffer-run-kill-buffers)` to my init.el and using that after marking multiple buffers. My default `tab` actions had no option to kill buffers.

Comment: For spacemacs users: instead of tabbing to select "kill buffers" press C-z, write "kill" and press RET

Comment: It seems helm (probably some emacs extension) is not installed by default on Ubuntu.; I've succeeded doing it using ibuffer (currenctly shown below this answer).

Answer (score 19):

`C-x C-b` to list all buffers 
`k` to mark buffers for kill (D appears next to buffer) 
`x` to execute kill

Comment: This one is nicer than helm mini and buffers. Yet, the newly opened "Buffer List" does not receive input focus after `C-x C-b`, strange.

Comment: For me, I had to use `d` to mark a buffer for deletion.

Answer (score 11):

Using helm:

1. Open helm using `helm-mini`. In my case I have it mapped to <kbd>C-2</kbd>
2. Scroll through the list and mark the ones you want to delete with <kbd>C-Space</kbd>
3. Now just press <kbd>M-S-d</kbd> / <kbd>M-D</kbd>

This deletes all selected buffers and closes `helm-mini`.